# F# - creating 100 objects into a List - most functional and idiomatic way

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, idioms

In F# what is the most functional and idiomatic way of creating or "newing up" 100 new objects into a List.

I guess for an example we could use DateTime as an example object.

Comment: in scheme we just did (and I'm rusty at this): declare appendlist list xtogo append (if (> x 0) (appendlist (cons list append) (- xtogo 1) append) (list))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List.init 100 (fun x -> x * 2)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. 
List.init 100 (fun x -> new System.DateTime())

Comment: Arguably even slightly more idiomatic (and shorter): `List.init 100 (fun _ -> DateTime())`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, as a list expression:

```
[for i in 1..100 -> new System.DateTime()]
```

But I think this is less idiomatic.

Comment: @Ingo: In F# you have "sequences" for stuff like that. `(Seq.initInfinite id)` are the non-negative integers, for example.

Comment: @Ingo: F# has `List.replicate`, `Seq.take`, `Seq.iter` and so forth. F# also has some nice advantages, like `List.ofArray` doesn't stack overflow as `getElems` does in Haskell. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using

```
[|for i in 1..100 -> new System.DateTime() |]
```

since you are working with mutable data.

Comment: Since when is `DateTime` mutable?

Comment: Yea, I just tried to down-vote my answer. Can't remember if it was a struct or class. Should probably just use a float anyway.

Comment: Whether to use an immutable or a mutable collection (like array) does not really depend on the mutability of the element type. It is perfectly okay to have an array of an immutable type. - One has to be careful with sorted collection like `Map`, though. Changing a mutable key element of a `Map` is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @Brent, you cracked me up with "just tried to down-vote my answer". BTW - DateTime is a struct / ValueType. And I don't what you mean talking about floats.

Comment: You just created an array, not a list. didn't you?

Comment: Yea. I just created an array.